# Better Solution to append text to select element Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function like :

```
function test(element_name){
  $("#"+element_name).show();
}
```

Now, this  `$("#"+element_name).show();` is giving some security concern.  So, is there a better way to select the element using the element_name passed. That can be used as an alternative.

An automated code review application is marking this as concern : `"This may enable a DOM XSS attack."`

Comment: pass element_id? `$('#element_id').show()`?

Comment: ___`some security concern`___ ? What is that ?

Comment: I am curious, why is this a security concern? If this is a security concern, all other alternatives will also be a security concern without involving server-side.

Comment: `element_name` is a variable .. So we need to append # to it to select the element.

Comment: I dont think its security concern.

Comment: What security issues you see here? That user will force some element show? Validate ID's than

Comment: @Sameer "This may enable a DOM XSS attack."

Comment: If it is an element *name* then it doesn't make sense to prepend the `#` *id* selector. But anyway, if you have an element id in a variable (for whatever reason) then `$("#"+element_name)` is the correct way to select the element.  I don't see how XSS attacks would be an issue given that you can't `.show()` an element that doesn't exist.

Comment: @atulquest93, Whole javascript code can be modified by the user as they like. No matter how much you cange this code, a user will always be able to do anything they want in the javascript.

Comment: @atulquest93, pls read nnnnnn's comment

Comment: If hide or show an element of your page can create security problems. Problems are in your page not in the JS method

Comment: @Alexis hide show is just to illustrate , problem is with selecting the id.. The code review application is marking this.

Comment: How is `element_name` set? What possible values could it have?

Comment: @nnnnnn it can have any value basically its containing a division id..

Comment: But where do the values come from? Can they possibly be set or saved by a user, or are they only set programmatically?

Comment: Passing the value manually from the js fucntion manually, the value will remain same. Issue is not value .. The main problem is will this really be able to make DOM XSS

Comment: How the value is set *is* relevant to whether it could be used for an XSS attack. If it's not coming from user input I don't see how it could be a security problem - user can mess up the page in their own browser as much as they like, but unless they can somehow store the value on your server it can't affect anybody else.

Answer (score 1):

Since the javascript (and the "hidden" content) is client-side, there's no security worth mentioning anyway. The client cannot be trusted.

If you need the string provided to the function to not be parsed, use `document.getElementById` instead:

```
function test(element_name){
  $(document.getElementById(element_name)).show();
}
```

Comment: I know this but, the code review application is marking this as a high priority concern. `This may enable a DOM XSS attack.`

Comment: @atulquest93 Perhaps my update will help with your security review. Keep in mind that code review applications are advisory. On the one hand, you should not just follow their directives blindly; on the other hand, you should have valid reason to ignore any particular warning they provide.

Comment: Is there some way that jQuery could parse the string that would be a security concern? (Given that the string it is receiving would start with a `#`.)

Comment: @Ouroborus exactly, but i need to provide the explanation against every check-mark generated. Thanks will update the code.. Hope this fixes the issue.

Comment: But, Yes I'm just curious about the issue... Will that would really cause a XSS DOM attack ?

Comment: @atulquest93 @nnnnnn jQuery accepts several different kinds of inputs. For example `$('<div>Whee</div>')` creates a `div` with content. One might think you could use this to generate a `script` tag with content, though modern browsers don't allow it, this used to be a concern. In the case OP specifies, worst case scenario is the script throws an error or the jQuery doesn't select anything.

Comment: I know `$()` allows a few options, but as I mentioned *this* string would always start with a `#` so I think jQuery would treat it as a selector. In any case, even if it could be executed as a script, if `element_name`'s value isn't coming from a user-entered value stored on the web server it isn't going to be able to do any XSS stuff.

Comment: @nnnnnn As near as I can tell, prepending `#` is enough to get jQuery to think you're using a CSS selector and treating the argument as such. But I don't know. And I won't know unless I go through the jQuery code. And even then I might not know because there may be some obscure zero-day exploit related to it. But you're right in that, if you can show the content of that variable is entirely under control of the server from the time its content was created to the time it was sent to the client, and at no time was a user allowed to have any influence over it, the warning is probably a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if the element is a child of a certain object or you can add custom tags to the elements that should be able to .show() and check for them but I guess there is no other "secure way" to allocate an object via ID.